# Machine Learning with APIs and storing results

Tags: machine-learning, caching, google-api, google-places-api, data-science

I have a (commercial) machine learning project where I want to enrich the existing information with data from different API sources (like Google Places, Facebook Graph), save this in a database and analyse the whole data with machine learning algorithms (e.g. perform clustering).

But according to e.g. Google Places caching and storing data is not allowed:

> 3.2.4 (a)  No Scraping. Customer will not extract, export, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download Google Maps tiles, Street View images, geocodes, directions, distance matrix results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license
>
> 3.2.4 (b) No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms
>   https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license
>
> 5.4 Caching. Customer can temporarily cache latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) values from the Places API for up to 30 consecutive calendar days, after which Customer must delete the cached latitude and longitude values. Customer can cache Places API Place ID (place_id) values, in accordance with the Places API Policies.
>   https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/

How did you proceed in similar projects? Is it really caching what I want to do in the project or is there a slight difference? I've made a request to Google but they couldn't answer this question on the telephone. And I need to store the data somewhere to be able to perform the machine learning algorithms.

Comment: you can get the data, train the models and delete the data or extracting/projecting the data to some other feature set and store this, instead of the data itself